# Creating an array issue

Tags: java, arrays, object-oriented-analysis

I wrote this code but it says statement 6 is an error
could someone tell me whats wrong please

```
public class arraytest{
private int a[];
private int noe; //number of elememtos
public arraytest(){
noe=5;
a[5];}
}
public void read(){
a[0]=5;a[1]=3;a[2]=6;a[3]=9;a[4]=2;}
public int sum(){
int sum=0;
for (int i=0; i<a.length();i++)
sum=sum+a[i];
return sum;}

public static void main(String[]args){
arraytest x=new arraytest();
x.read();
System.out.println("The sum is " + x.sum());
}
}
```

Comment: You are not setting any value to the a[5]

Comment: You should format your code, its a good exercise to understanding it.

Answer (score 4):

ah, Rookie mistake

He thought he initialized the array with a[5] which is wrong

I'm guessing he tried to do this

```
public arraytest(){
 noe=5;
 a = new int[noe];
}
```

And dude, learn how to indent your code, so that it will be much readable to others trying to help you out

```
public class arraytest{
   private int a[];
   private int noe; //number of elememtos
   public arraytest(){
     noe=5;
     a = new int[noe];
   }

   public void read(){
     a[0]=5;a[1]=3;a[2]=6;a[3]=9;a[4]=2;
   }

   public int sum(){
     int sum=0;
     for (int i=0; i<a.length;i++)
     sum=sum+a[i];
     return sum;
   }

   public static void main(String[]args){
      arraytest x=new arraytest();
      x.read();
      System.out.println("The sum is " + x.sum());
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot, sorry im still a rookie, your correction works thanks alot for the hand

Comment: And just for the record: consider deleting no longer required comments ;-)

Comment: @HishamIbrahimRaGe:  if answer working for u, dont forgot to accept answer, this will help to future visitors

Answer (score 3):

```
a[5];
```

Is not a valid statement. You need to perform some assignment.

```
a[5] = 5; //for example
```

Comment: so what should i do brother.

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to accomplish with that line of code. The compiler has simply told you that you cannot just put `a[5];` as a line of code. You must do something with it.

Comment: There are other errors in your code too. You have curly brace matching issues, and there is no `length()` method for arrays, only a `length` field.

Comment: im trying to create an array  that reads the elements (noe=number of elements ) which are 5

Comment: okay the length should not have () , jgrasp program said arraytest.java:6: not a statement
a[5];}
 ^
arraytest.java:8: class, interface, or enum expected
public void read(){
       ^